# gcc is not compatible with 64 bit?

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, 64-bit

I install the cygwin and set the path to the C:\cygwin\bin, however when I run gcc in the command line, it shows the error as follows: 
[image]

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: It sounds like you installed an ancient 16-bit version of GCC. 16-bit executables can't run on 64-bit Windows. How exactly did you install Cygwin?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I install it by installing from internet and then choose a website. There are many urls listed, I choose the first one.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I download setup.exe from http://www.cygwin.com/install.html

Comment: In your `cygwin\bin` directory, do a `dir gcc*.exe` and tell us the output. You probably want `gcc-3.exe`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  GCC-3isOK, however, I need gcc.exx

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have a `gcc.exe` in there? I think you're trying to run some other `gcc` that has nothing to do with Cygwin (probably same ancient 16-bit `gcc`). If the `gcc-3.exe` that came with Cygwin is working, this isn't a Cygwin question.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes, I have gcc.exe and also gcc-3.exe. I have to run a software that based on gcc

Comment: And the `gcc.exe` is from your Cygwin install? Do you know which Cygwin package it came from? Your `gcc` should be a symlink to `gcc-3`. (You can hook it up however you want with the `alternatives` program.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes, from Cygwin Install. Now solved, just install gcc not from cygwin! Thank.

Comment: I can't understand what you're saying. You're going to have to be more specific if you want help. What is "yes" to? Are you trying to get Cygwin's `gcc` to work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that gcc.exe is a symlink to gcc-3.exe or gcc-4.exe. Cygwin understands symlinks (so invoking gcc from the cygwin shell will work), but windows cmd.exe does not.

I just copied gcc-4.exe to gcc.exe and now all is good.

Answer (score -2):

I see that cygwin have installer for 64 bit. Try to verify if is not for 32 bits. However, reinstall it from some mirror sites.

Comment: I just choose install from the first sites, so may you help me to give me the correct sites?

Comment: View some mirror ftp or HTTP, and take 64 bit version. You can see 64 bit as distinct directory.

Comment: 64-bit Cygwin is not ready for public use! Don't recommend new users use it! 32-bit Cygwin programs should work fine on 64-bit Windows; the problem here is something else.